# Django 1.5+ Admin Date Range Filter

Tags: python, django, filter, admin, date-range

Does anyone have any recommendations for Django 1.5+ compatible Date Range Filter for the Admin page, I have tried a bunch for 1.4 and it doesn't seem to work. And I know the 1.3 does not work at all. I just need something better than Any date, today, past 7 months, and etc... Need to be able to input specific day.

No luck on getting correct url like this: "?created_*gte=2013-06-27&created*_lt=2013-06-28"

The closest example I got was this: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-daterange-filter/0.2.1, but when I enter the range and hit submit, it does nothing.

Thanks much.

Comment: Maybe you can look at the source of django-daterange-filter and figure out why nothing's happening?

Comment: I tried, it looks like it should work, it picks up my field. But doesn't inject anything into URLS. Like the default filter.

Comment: hmm. 0.2.1 and django 1.5.2 works for me...

Comment: django-daterange-filter is also not working for me. I am on django 3.5.

Comment: the given app doesn't work for me. https://github.com/tzulberti/django-datefilterspec work for me in django 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this instead:

```
date_hierarchy = 'created'
```

it's a good enough feature for me to sort with.